# Why does python not replace words correctly from a data dictionary?

Tags: python

```
firstsentence=("an eye for an eye a tooth for a tooth")

def replace_all(firstsentence, stuff):
    for i, j in stuff.items():
        firstsentence = firstsentence.replace(i, j)
    return firstsentence
stuff = {"a": "1", "eye": "2", "for":"3", "tooth": "5", "an": "6"}
test=replace_all(firstsentence, stuff)
list(firstsentence)
list(test)




appendFile=open("task2.txt", "a")
appendFile.write(firstsentence+"\n")
appendFile.write(test+"\n")
appendFile.close()
```

In my code I replace the word sin the sentence with there positions. It works however it does not replace an correctly. This is the output

```
an eye for an eye a tooth for a tooth
1n 2 3 1n 2 1 5 3 1 5
```

It replaces the "a" in the word "an" as 1 but ignores the fact it is a whole word that is "an". Why does it do this?

Comment: Why are you calling `list(firstsentence)` and `list(test)`, but ignore the results? Both calls can be removed entirely without incident.

Answer (score 4):

`'an'.replace('a', 1)` is run **first**, giving you `'1n'`. `'1n'.replace('an', 6)` is not going to replace `1n`.

Sort your replacements by length to ensure that *longer* matches are handled first:

```
def replace_all(firstsentence, stuff):
    for i, j in sorted(stuff.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[0]), reverse=True):
        firstsentence = firstsentence.replace(i, j)
    return firstsentence
```

The `sorted()` function sorts the `(key, value)` tuples that `stuff.items()` produces, and it is instructed to sort by the length of the key (the `key` lambda is passed a tuple, and `kv[0]` is the dictionary key)). The sort order is reversed to put the longest keys first.

This way, you try to replace all instances of `an` before you replace instances of `a`.

Demo:

```
>>> def replace_all(firstsentence, stuff):
...     for i, j in sorted(stuff.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[0]), reverse=True):
...         firstsentence = firstsentence.replace(i, j)
...     return firstsentence
...
>>> stuff = {"a": "1", "eye": "2", "for":"3", "tooth": "5", "an": "6"}
>>> firstsentence = "an eye for an eye a tooth for a tooth"
>>> replace_all(firstsentence, stuff)
'6 2 3 6 2 1 5 3 1 5'
```

Note that this won't prevent partial replacement; If words like `animal` or `fortitude` appear in your text then you'll still see partial replacements. If you absolutely need to only replace whole words, you'll need to either split your sentence on whitespace and do direct dictionary lookups, or use a regular expression with `\b` word-boundary anchors.

Comment: It might be useful to add that `'an'.replace('a', 1)` does not always run first. There's about 50% change that the program returns the correct output due to hashing parameters varying with each run.

Answer (score 0):

First you should tokenize your line and extract words:

```
firstsentence="an eye for an eye a tooth for a tooth"

wordslist = firstsentence.split(' ')
```

Then you should build set or unique words (perhaps you should lowerize em first):

```
uwords = list(set([_.lower() for _ in wordslist]))
```

After this you can encode your text:

```
output = ' '.join([str(uwords.index(_)+1) for _ in wordslist])
```

So the result function would be:

```
def replace_all(sentence):
    wordslist = sentence.split(' ')
    uwords = list(set([_.lower() for _ in wordslist]))
    return ' '.join([str(uwords.index(_.lower())+1) for _ in wordslist])
```

Or if you have fixed wordsmap:

```
def replace_all(sentence, stuff):
    wordslist = sentence.split(' ')
    return ' '.join([stuff[_] for _ in wordslist])
```